# doctrine query builder join materialized view

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql, materialized-views

using Symfony 3.2.4, doctrine and postgres 9.6, I've 2 tables with big data, and I need to obtain result join table records (with sql function es: sum, avg, etc) in acceptable times.

Well, I've create a materialized view, and now it's so really speedy!

YEAH!

But... how I can execute DQL query with Doctrine/Symfony??

I tried to generate entity from materialized view, but it is not detected.

> D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\myproject>php bin\console
>   doctrine:mapping:import BackendBundle annotation
>   --filter= 
>   Database does not have any mapping information.

So, I tried to write simple query, but doctrine expect a bundle Entity...

> [2017-04-03 23:13:37] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 80
>   near 'Stats': Error: Class 'Stats' is not defined."
>   at
>   D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php
>   line 63 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): [Semantical Error]
>   line 0, col 80 near 'stats': Error: Class 'Stats' is
>   not defined. at
>   D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:63,
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): SELECT
>   stasgeojson(l.geom) as geom FROM BackendBundle:MyTable l LEFT
>   JOIN Stats stats WITH stats.key=l.key WHERE l.filter
>   in (77004) at
>   D:\eclipse_neon_workspace\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:41)"}
>   []

How the hell do I use a materialized view with doctrine????

Thx in Advance

Comment: Can you please show the code that caused the above error?

Comment: $qb->select("field1")->from("BackendBundle:Table", "t")->join("Stats","stats",Join::WITH,"t.key=stats.key")->where("t.field2 in (3456)");

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found no solutions.... DQL don't support VIEW or MATERIALIZED VIEW, and there's nothing for generate entities from these object.

So, I've create a simple $em->createNativeQuery using native SQL, and it all works, but I think that's a gap of no small importance